# javascript forEach manage exceptions

Tags: javascript, testing, foreach, error-handling, throw

I have a forEach loop that check if there are conditions before pushing data in the array:

```
allow(id, perm, arr) {
  const data = { "userId": id, "permissionId": perm };

  arr.forEach(key => {
    if (id !== key.userId) {
      throw new Error('id does not exists');
    } else {
      if (perm === key.permissionId) {
        throw new Error('perm exists in this id');
      } else {
        arr.push(data);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The original array `arr` is like this:

```
[{"userId": 1,"permissionId": 1},
 {"userId": 2,"permissionId": 1},
 {"userId": 3,"permissionId": 0},
 {"userId": 4,"permissionId": 0}]
```

if I use `console.log()` all works, but when I throw an error the execution stops, but how can I manage the exceptions without stop looping?

Comment: Just on another note for using exceptions inside the forEach. it is usually not recommended to use forEach loop if you have to throw an exception inside. Its rather useful to use `every`, `some`. This is defined in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`throw` is designed to stop your loop/code invocation. If you want to throw those errors after loop, you can push all errors to the array and throw them at the end:

```
allow(id, perm, arr) {
  const data = { "userId": id, "permissionId": perm };
  const errors = [];

  arr.forEach(key => {
    if (id !== key.userId) {
      errors.push('id does not exists');
    } else {
      if (perm === key.permissionId) {
        errors.push('perm exists in this id');
      } else {
        arr.push(data);
      }
    }
  });

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    throw new Error(errors.join());
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but how can I use the errors array? I'm using jest and I have the `id does not exists` output only, even with `id = 1`

Answer (score -1):

Try catching the exceptions you throw.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp